# How to change the Accept-Language for the entire session of a C# web browser component?

Tags: c#, winforms, header, webbrowser-control

How to change the Accept-Language for the entire session of a C# web browser component ?

I used the following code :

```
webbrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com",null,null,"Accept-Language: "+lang+"\r\n");
```

But this works only for the first loaded page.

I think I need to load the winINet.dll file but I don't know how to manipulate it .

Any help please ?

Edit 1:

My app is in C# and I'm using the web browser component . Please make sure you read the tags before flagging questions.

and I already searched the forum for hours.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decide the language from cookies/headers/session in webapp2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514017/how-to-decide-the-language-from-cookies-headers-session-in-webapp2)

Comment: My app is in C# and I'm using the web browser component . Please make sure you read the tags before flagging questions.